# Issue getting file array variable within a different array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am in the process of moving PHP code for a file upload system to its own file, so I can upload the file with AJAX.

I am running into an issue where I can't get this updated code:

```
$filename       =   $fileArray[$fileNameVar];
$tmp_name       =   $fileArray[$fileTmpNameVar];
$filesize       =   $fileArray[$fileSizeVar];
$file_error     =   $fileArray[$fileErrorVar];
$file           =   $fileArray[$p_img];
```

To operate how it used to, like this:

```
$filename       =   $fileArray['file']['name'];
$tmp_name       =   $fileArray['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize       =   $fileArray['file']['size'];
$file_error     =   $fileArray['file']['error'];
$file           =   $fileArray['file'];
```

When I try to `var_dump` anything from the set of new variables, I get nothing showing up in the response.

Does anyone know how I need to setup this array?

Here is the full code:

```
$p_img = $_FILES['file'];
//var_dump($p_img);

$fileNameVar = $p_img['name'];
$fileTmpNameVar = $p_img['tmp_name'];
$fileSizeVar = $p_img['size'];
$fileErrorVar = $p_img['error'];

//$fileFileVar = $p_img['file'];
try {
// If you make a file function, you can change where things are saved
// You can also change the destination (for portability)
    function UploadFile($fileArray = array(), $destinationFolder = '../project_images/') {
       /* $filename       =   $fileArray['file']['name'];
        $tmp_name       =   $fileArray['file']['tmp_name'];
        $filesize       =   $fileArray['file']['size'];
        $file_error     =   $fileArray['file']['error'];
        $file           =   $fileArray['file'];
       */
        $filename       =   $fileArray[$fileNameVar];
        $tmp_name       =   $fileArray[$fileTmpNameVar];
        $filesize       =   $fileArray[$fileSizeVar];
        $file_error     =   $fileArray[$fileErrorVar];
        $file           =   $fileArray[$p_img];

        var_dump($filename);
        // Save all the default data.
        // Success and error should be set by default to fail
        $return['error']        =   true;
        $return['success']      =   false;
        $return['file']['dest'] =   $destinationFolder.$filename;
        $return['file']['size'] =   $filesize;

        if($file_error == 0)
            $return['error']    =   false;
        // I added a directory creation function so you don't have to 
        // manually make folders. This will do it for you.
        if(!is_dir($destinationFolder))
            mkdir($destinationFolder,0755,true);
        // If your filename is not empty, return success or fail of upload
        if (!empty($filename))
            $return['success']  = (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename));

        return $return;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('error_log_top', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Error adding attachment: \n" . print_r($e, 1), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

EDIT: How I call the uplaodFile function:

```
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
    // Try uploading
    $upload =   UploadFile($_FILES);
    // If upload fails
    if(!$upload['success']) {
        echo '<h3>Sorry, an error occurred</h3>';
    }
    else {
        // You could add error handling here based on the results of 
        // each function's success or failure below.

        // Try to save it
        $saveToDb   =   SaveToDb($con,$upload['file']['dest']);
        // Get the profile from image name
        $profPic    =   ($saveToDb)? getPhoto($con,$upload['file']['dest']) : false;   
    }
}
```

Edit - Updated Code:

```
function UploadFile($fileArray, $destinationFolder = '../project_images/') {
    $fileUploadData = $fileArray['file'];
    $filename       =   $fileUploadData['name'];
    $tmp_name       =   $fileUploadData['tmp_name'];
    $filesize       =   $fileUploadData['size'];
    $file_error     =   $fileUploadData['error'];

    var_dump($filename);
    // Save all the default data.
    // Success and error should be set by default to fail
    $return['error']        =   true;
    $return['success']      =   false;
    $return['file']['dest'] =   $destinationFolder.$filename;
    $return['file']['size'] =   $filesize;

    if($file_error == 0)
        $return['error']    =   false;

    if(!is_dir($destinationFolder))
        mkdir($destinationFolder,0755,true);
    // If your filename is not empty, return success or fail of upload
    if (!empty($filename))
        $return['success']  = (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename));

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You should show how you call the `UploadFile` function.

Comment: You probably want to move all this: `$p_img =...= $p_img['error']` to the beginning of `UploadFile` function, and change `$p_img = $_FILES['file'];` to `$p_img = $fileArray['file'];`

Comment: the `$fileNameVar` var declared outside of the function so you can use it inside. You also never init `$return` - it may work but you better do it...

Comment: I have never seen anyone put a function declaration inside a try/catch.

Comment: @HTMHell The reason for `$p_img = $_FILES['file'];` was to get the file info from the html file. When I just changed it, it threw an error that $fileArray was not defined. I then put `$p_img = $fileArray['file'];` into the `UploadFile` function. My `var_dump` isn't outputting anything.

Answer (score 0):

This: (won't work)

```
$filename       =   $fileArray[$fileNameVar];
$tmp_name       =   $fileArray[$fileTmpNameVar];
$filesize       =   $fileArray[$fileSizeVar];
$file_error     =   $fileArray[$fileErrorVar];
$file           =   $fileArray[$p_img];
```

Is not the same as this: (will work)

```
$filename       =   $fileArray['file']['name'];
$tmp_name       =   $fileArray['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize       =   $fileArray['file']['size'];
$file_error     =   $fileArray['file']['error'];
$file           =   $fileArray['file'];
```

In this code, $fileArray is an array of arrays. 
Therefore, you can't treat it as a single dimensional array and expect to get actual values from it.

When you do this:

```
$p_img = $_FILES['file'];
$fileNameVar = $p_img['name'];
$fileTmpNameVar = $p_img['tmp_name'];
$fileSizeVar = $p_img['size'];
$fileErrorVar = $p_img['error'];
```

Each of these are the actual values.
i.e. `$fileNameVar` contains the actual original name of the file when it was uploaded.

What you could do is this:

```
$fileUploadData = $fileArray['file'];
$filename       =   $fileUploadData['name'];
$tmp_name       =   $fileUploadData['tmp_name'];
$filesize       =   $fileUploadData['size'];
$file_error     =   $fileUploadData['error'];
// Other code goes here.
```

Other thoughts:

```
function UploadFile($fileArray = array(), $destinationFolder = '../project_images/')
```

Should be:

```
function UploadFile($fileArray, $destinationFolder = '../project_images/')
```

It makes no sense to have a default. There is nothing sensible to do in that case if the array is empty.

Comment: I just added my updated code to my question. Is that what you are saying to do? My `var_dump` isn't outputting anything still.

Comment: Then you need to debug the code. Output everything to the screen or a log file.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with the try/catch, but didn't know it wouldn't work. I have `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the file and then added the `var_dump`. I'm not sure how to send everything to a log file. The normal `error_log` file is not producing any errors.

Comment: Do I not need the `$_FILES['file']`?

Comment: Here is a simple logger that you can use for debugging. https://gist.github.com/ryantxr/fb2b2fa9fa63b34a1bd9

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Why don't I need this anywhere? `$_FILES['file']` Isn't that how I get the file info from the html file to the php file?